# How to simplify my code by using a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to obtain the subtotal (average, min, max...) of a group of data. I have achieve the goal using the code below. How can I use loop to simplify it? Many thanks!

```
Sub AddSubs()
    Worksheets("Summary (3)").Activate
    'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838166(v=office.15).aspx
    Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=14, Function:=xlAverage, SummaryBelowData:=False, Replace:=False, PageBreaks:=True, TotalList:=Array(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39)
    Worksheets("Summary (3)").Activate
    Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=14, Function:=xlStDev, SummaryBelowData:=False, Replace:=False, PageBreaks:=True, TotalList:=Array(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39)
    Worksheets("Summary (3)").Activate
    Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=14, Function:=xlMin, SummaryBelowData:=False, Replace:=False, PageBreaks:=True, TotalList:=Array(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39)
    Worksheets("Summary (3)").Activate
    Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=14, Function:=xlMax, SummaryBelowData:=False, Replace:=False, PageBreaks:=True, TotalList:=Array(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39)
    Worksheets("Summary (3)").Activate
    Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=14, Function:=xlCount, SummaryBelowData:=False, Replace:=False, PageBreaks:=True, TotalList:=Array(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39)
End Sub
```

Comment: The only thing that needs simplification are the Function:= parameters. What I would do is create an enumerable list with all those constants and then iterate over it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to my comment. This is one way of simplifying your code

```
Sub AddSubs()
    Worksheets("Summary (3)").Activate

    Dim constList As Collection
    Set constList = New Collection

    constList.Add (xlAverage)
    constList.Add (xlStDev)
    constList.Add (xlMin)
    constList.Add (xlMax)
    constList.Add (xlCount)

    Dim cnst
    For Each cnst In constList
        Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=14, Function:=cnst, SummaryBelowData:=False, Replace:=False, PageBreaks:=True, TotalList:=Array(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39)
    Next

End Sub
```

or even simpler (per @simocos hint)

```
Sub Main()

    Dim cnst
    For Each cnst In Array(xlAverage, xlStDev, xlMin, xlMax, xlCount)
        Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=14, Function:=cnst, SummaryBelowData:=False, Replace:=False, PageBreaks:=True, TotalList:=Array(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: +1, in second code change `For Each cnst In constList` to `For Each cnst In c`. Btw, why not `For Each cnst In Array(xlAverage, xlStDev, xlMin, xlMax, xlCount)`?

Comment: @simoco definitely +1 to you I was in the middle of something and answered without thinking through

Comment: Is there anyway to simplify the numbers in    Array(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39)?

Comment: you can make a loop to populate an array with numbers from 3 to 39 and then use that array instead of Array(3....)

Comment: @user2230101, or use direct `For cnst =3 To 39`